# В какой последовательности нужно располагать медиа запросы?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Код:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper.agy {
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .left-sidebar.agy,
  .content.agy,
  .right-sidebar.agy {
    float: left;
  }

  .left-sidebar.agy,
  .right-sidebar.agy {
    width: 320px;
  }

  .content.agy {
    width: calc(100% - 320px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .main-post-poster img {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-post-poster img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  @media (max-width: 992px) {
    .post-controls-calendar {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Форматировал ваш код, заметил что, возможно, там опечатка (ближе к низу).

Comment: А в чём вопрос? В какой хотите в такой и располагайте, главное, что был желаемый результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если верстка от меньшего к большему, то и запросы так же идут :

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  ...
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  ...
}

...
```

Если от большего к меньшему, то и запросы так же:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  ...
} 

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  ...
}

...
```

Т.е.:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper.agy {
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .left-sidebar.agy,
  .content.agy,
  .right-sidebar.agy {
    float: left;
  }

  .left-sidebar.agy,
  .right-sidebar.agy {
    width: 320px;
  }

  .content.agy {
    width: calc(100% - 320px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .main-post-poster img {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .post-controls-calendar {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-post-poster img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```